# WXPython interface when moving from Windows to Linux is not working properly

Tags: python, linux, windows, matplotlib, wxpython

I almost finished a trial version of my graphic interface. I did that on Windows and then I move to Linux to test it.
The problem I am having is that the Matplotlib panel is being cut (just on Linux version), so I cannot see the graphic. I can't just resize to solve this.

Below you can see my code. Any ideas?

```
 # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import wx
import sys
import numpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas, \
    NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx

ini3=0
fin3=0
pico3=[]
nomeAbre3=''
iniespec=0
intervaloespec=400


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(2000,800))
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.p1 = MainPanel(self.sp)
        self.p2 = MatplotPanel(self.sp)
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.box.Add(self.p1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.box.Add(self.p2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.p2.draw()
        self.create_menu()

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(self.box)
        self.Layout()
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Oi')

    def create_menu(self):
        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        menu_file = wx.Menu()
        m_expt = menu_file.Append(-1, "&Save plot\tCtrl-S", "Save plot to file")

        menu_file.AppendSeparator()
        m_exit = menu_file.Append(-1, "E&xit\tCtrl-X", "Exit")


        menu_help = wx.Menu()
        m_about = menu_help.Append(-1, "&About\tF1", "About the demo")


        self.menubar.Append(menu_file, "&File")
        self.menubar.Append(menu_help, "&Help")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        """ Creates the main panel with all the controls on it:
             * mpl canvas 
             * mpl navigation toolbar
             * Control panel for interaction
        """
        self.nomeAbre = 'Spectrum'
        self.nomeFundo = 'Spectrum2'
        self.tipoDoAjuste = '1'
        self.grauDoFundo = '2'
        self.posicaoDosPicos = ''
        self.regiaoDoAjusteI = ''
        self.regiaoDoAjusteF = ''

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.dpi = 100
        self.fig = Figure((10.0, 6.0), dpi=self.dpi)

        self.abreArquivo = wx.Button(self, -1, "Open:", (10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openFile, self.abreArquivo)
        self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=self.nomeAbre, pos=(100, 10), size=(200,-1))
        self.AbreArquivoFundo = wx.Button(self, -1, "Fundo:", (10,40))
        self.editname2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=self.nomeFundo, pos=(100, 40), size=(200,-1))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openFile2, self.AbreArquivoFundo)


        self.ajusteTipo = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "A:", pos=(20, 80))
        self.ajusteTipoCaixa = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=self.tipoDoAjuste, pos=(100, 78), size=(25,-1))

        self.fundoGrau = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "B parameter:", pos=(140, 80))
        self.fundoGrauCaixa = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=self.grauDoFundo, pos=(220, 78), size=(25,-1))

        self.posicaoPicos = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Posicao dos Picos (max. 10 valores):", pos=(20, 120))
        self.posicaoPicosCaixa = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=self.posicaoDosPicos, pos=(245, 118), size=(350,-1))

        self.regiaoAjuste = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Regiao do Ajuste:", pos=(20, 160))
        self.regiaoAjusteI = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='', pos=(140, 158), size=(60,-1))
        self.regiaoAjusteF = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='', pos=(220, 158), size=(60,-1))

        self.inicioEspectroTexto = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Start:", pos=(250, 302))
        self.inicioEspectro = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", pos=(300, 300))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT,self.funcInicioEspectro,self.inicioEspectro)

        self.intervaloEspectroTexto = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Interval:", pos=(420, 302))
        self.intervaloEspectro = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "400", pos=(490, 300),size=(50,-1))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT,self.funcintervaloEspectro,self.intervaloEspectro)

        self.idf = wx.Button(self, -1, "IDF", (100,300))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.criaIDF,self.idf)

        global ini3
        global fin3
        global pico3
        global iniespec
        global intervaloespec
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION,lambda event:  self.OnMove(event,ini3,1))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION,lambda event:  self.OnMove(event,fin3,2))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION,lambda event:  self.OnMove(event,pico3,3))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION,lambda event:  self.OnMove(event,iniespec,4))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION,lambda event:  self.OnMove(event,intervaloespec,5))



    def criaIDF(self, event):
        a1 = nomeAbre3
        a2 = str(len(pico3))+','+str(ini3)+','+str(fin3)+',,'
        for j in pico3:
            a2 += str(j) + ','
        a2 += ','
        print(a1)
        print(a2)

    def funcInicioEspectro(self,event):
        global iniespec
        iniespec = self.inicioEspectro.GetValue()

    def funcintervaloEspectro(self,event):
        global intervaloespec
        intervaloespec = self.intervaloEspectro.GetValue()



    def showFrame(self, msg):
        """
        Shows the frame and shows the message sent in the
        text control
        """
        self.regiaoAjusteI.SetValue(msg.data)

    def openFile(self, event):
        wildcard = "Dat (*.dat)|*.dat|" \
        "All files (*.*)|*.*"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "", wildcard, wx.OPEN)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            global nomeAbre3
            nomeAbre3 = dialog.GetPath()
            self.editname.SetValue("%s" % (nomeAbre3))

        dialog.Destroy()




    def openFile2(self, event):
        wildcard = "CHN (*.chn)|*.chn|" \
        "Dat (*.dat)|*.dat|" \
        "All files (*.*)|*.*"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "", wildcard, wx.OPEN)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.nomeFundo = dialog.GetPath()
            self.editname2.SetValue("%s" % (self.nomeFundo))

        dialog.Destroy()

    def OnMove(self, event, valorInicial, escolha):
        if escolha == 1:
            self.regiaoAjusteI.SetValue("%s" % (str(valorInicial)))
            event.Skip()
        if escolha == 2:
            self.regiaoAjusteF.SetValue("%s" % (str(valorInicial)))
            event.Skip()
        if escolha == 3:
            self.posicaoPicosCaixa.SetValue("%s" % (' '.join(map(str, pico3))))
            event.Skip()
        if escolha == 4:
            self.inicioEspectro.SetValue("%s" % (str(iniespec)))
            event.Skip()
        if escolha == 5:
            self.intervaloEspectro.SetValue("%s" % (str(intervaloespec)))
            event.Skip()



class MatplotPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        global ini3
        self.mem = 0
        self.t=[]
        self.maxi=0

        self.ini = 0
        self.fin = 0
        self.pico = []

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas)

        self.toolbar.Realize()      

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.abreEspectro = wx.Button(self, -1, "Iniciar",size=(100,30))
        self.sizer.Add(self.abreEspectro,wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.modDraw, self.abreEspectro)       

        self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)


        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.cid_up = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.OnClick)
        self.cid_press = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.press)
        self.msg = self.mem


    def draw(self):
        self.t = np.arange(0.0, 300.0, 0.01)
        self.axes.plot(self.t)

    def modDraw(self, event):
        self.abre = open(nomeAbre3)
        self.t=(self.abre.read()).split('\n')

        self.axes.clear()        

        self.axes.plot(self.t)

        self.figure.canvas.draw()

        '''self.axes.set_xlim([0,len(t)])'''

    def OnClick(self, event):
        if event.dblclick:
            print("DBLCLICK", event)
        else:
            print("DOWN    ", event.xdata)
            self.mem = event.xdata

    def press(self, event):
        print('press', event.key)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if event.key=='i':
            global ini3
            ini3 = int(round(self.mem))
            self.ini = round(self.mem)

            print(self.ini)

        if event.key=='o':
            global fin3
            fin3 = int(round(self.mem))
            self.fin = round(self.mem)
            print(self.fin)

        if event.key=='p':
            global pico3
            pico3.append(int(round(self.mem)))
            self.pico.append(round(self.mem))
            print(self.pico)

        if event.key=='q':
            global pico3
            global fin3
            global ini3
            fin3 = 0
            ini3 = 0
            pico3 = []
            print(ini3)

        if event.key=='w':
            global pico3
            if len(pico3)>=1:
                del pico3[-1]
            print(fin3)

        if event.key=='e':
            global iniespec
            global intervaloespec
            self.axes.set_xlim([int(iniespec),int(iniespec)+int(intervaloespec)])
            maxim = self.maxY(int(iniespec),int(iniespec)+int(intervaloespec))
            self.axes.set_ylim(0,maxim+100)
            self.figure.canvas.draw()

        if event.key=='d':
            global iniespec
            global intervaloespec
            iniespec = int(iniespec)+int(intervaloespec) - 10
            self.axes.set_xlim([int(iniespec),int(iniespec)+int(intervaloespec)+10])
            maxim = self.maxY(int(iniespec),int(iniespec)+int(intervaloespec))
            self.axes.set_ylim(0,maxim+100)
            self.figure.canvas.draw()


    def maxY(self,a,b):
        self.maxi = int(self.t[a])
        for i in range(a,b):
            if self.maxi < int(self.t[i]):
                self.maxi = int(self.t[i])
        return(self.maxi)

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = TestFrame(None, 'Hello World!')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal amount of code that will reproduce your problem?  With this much code, not many people will bother to read your question.

Comment: Thanks, @tcaswell, but Luke WoodWard solved my problem. Next time I do that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you're having is that you are adding the *children* of the splitter window to the `BoxSizer` `self.box`, when you should be adding the splitter window itself.

Instead of writing

```
        self.box.Add(self.p1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.box.Add(self.p2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

write

```
        self.box.Add(self.sp, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

You'll also need to tell the splitter-window which way to split, horizontally or vertically, using, for example

```
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.p1, self.p2)
```

Finally, as you're not using a Sizer for your `MainPanel`, you might want to set a minimum size for it.  I found that the splitter window didn't show the MainPanel at all if I didn't give it a minimum size (or didn't restrict the minimum size of a pane in the splitter window using `SetMinimumPanelSize`).  Try adding the following to the bottom of `MainPanel.__init__` (change the numbers if you wish):

```
        self.SetMinSize((350, 350))
```

I'm using wxWidgets/wxPython 2.9.4 on Python 2.7.3 on openSUSE 12.3 x64, if that helps.